# iOS ECONNRESET with incomplete TLS handshake - generating errSSLClosedNoNotify

Tags: ios, ssl, tls1.2

When we try to access one API from the iOS application running on iOS 13 using cellular (4G), it shows intermittent error:

```
[] -[NWConcrete_nw_address_endpoint initWithAddress:overridePort:] Fixing endpoint address with non-zero sin_zero field
[] tcp_input [C4.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=4011135460, ack=1357945681, win=0 state=ESTABLISHED rcv_nxt=4011135460, snd_una=1357945681
Connection 4: received failure notification
Connection 4: received ECONNRESET with incomplete TLS handshake - generating errSSLClosedNoNotify
Connection 4: failed to connect 3:-9816, reason -1
Connection 4: encountered error(3:-9816)
Task <50BECA08-D337-4DA7-A57C-D04AAAE2367C>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9816])
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200
```

But, the above error never happens on the same iPhone, same app when connecting to wifi.

Interestingly, when we use the same phone connecting to the same wifi, but using safari to hit the same API, it got no issue.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you figure out why this is occurring? I think I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I created a package to help with TLS Sockets/iOS/Obj-C. I also included a lot of good info about creating certificates correctly given the latest iOS 13 restrictions.

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets/tree/master

Comment: That's good. However, he clearly said intermittent error and that it works on WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

Either restarting or go to `Settings` -> `General` -> `Reset` -> `Reset All Settings` solved it for me on iOS 14.4 and iPhone 8